# Converting symbols to English: $(\forall x)D(x)$, $(\exists x)D(x)$, $\lnot (\exists x)D(x)$, $(\exists x)\lnot (Dx)$

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

The domain is all penguins.  D(x) = "x is dangerous"

$(\forall x)D(x)$

All penguins are dangerous

$(\exists x)D(x)$

Some penguins are dangerous

$\lnot (\exists x)D(x)$

There is not a penguin that is dangerous

$(\exists x)\lnot (Dx)$

There is a penguin that is not dangerous

Are these right?  I keep going back and forth on the third and fourth ones.

Comment: What is "(Vx)"? $\;$

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do the right symbol, it should be an upside down A.  "for all x".

Comment: @KKendall Evidently, someone else changed it.  But, you do `$\forall$`.  That makes $\forall$

Comment: I changed it. $\;$

Answer (score 4):

All of your translations are correct.

For the third expression $\neg \exists x ~ D(x)$, we can alternatively translate it to mean: "It is not the case that there exists some penguin that is dangerous." or, more succinctly: "No penguin is dangerous.". Since this expression is equivalent to $\forall x ~ \neg D(x)$, we can also translate the same expression to mean: "Every penguin is not dangerous."